# Как эмулируют cloudflare каптчу сервисы

Tags: javascript, captcha, cloudflare

Есть множество сервисов для разгадывания каптчи Rucaptcha anticaptcha и прочие.

Мне интересно как они эмулируют форму на своем сайте лишь по 2 данным sitekey и url. Ведь для создания каптчи нужен secret key. Буду признателен за подсказки как эмулируют форму cloudflare для решения людьми

Comment: Зачем её создавать? Запросить у сервера так же, как это делает браузер, да и всё, никакой secret key для этого не нужен

Comment: Не могли бы привести пример кода, использую код из github cloudflare но она просто не грузится